# What's the opposite of "enlarge"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, antonyms

In the context of a computer user interface manual, what word would you use to complete this sentence:

> Drag the handle at the bottom-right corner to enlarge or **__** the window.

To me, "shrink", "diminish", and "reduce" all feel wrong in this context. Is there a better word? (Or would one of those work if I changed the word "enlarge" to something else?)

Comment: How about just rephrasing to "Drag the handle at the bottom-right corner to make the window larger or smaller"?

Comment: Even simpler: "...to resize the window". That's what everyone else says. OP is just being needlessly verbose.

Comment: ...apropos which, since window resizing is pretty much standard on all UI's nowadays, why mention it at all. Is this manual going to explain how to 'drag' the handle?

Comment: Disembiggen, perhaps?

Comment: @callum: What, don't you ever say "ensmall"? :P

Comment: The real problem is that there does not exist the word "ensmall". Any other words do not seem to pair perfectly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using "shrink" as an antonym for "enlarge" in this context. If "enlarge" bothers you, you might try pairing "shrink" with "expand".

Answer (score 6):

The antonyms are **reduce** or **shrink**, depending on the meaning. For example *if the space is enlarged, it may be reduced to its initial size*.

Answer (score 3):

"ensmall" perhaps? Shrink is the correct word, it shouldn't feel wrong.

Comment: *Ensmall* is a common error. The word is ***ensmallen***. It's the opposite of *embiggen*. And yes, they're both perfectly cromulent words.

Comment: +1 for Shrink: I think that it sounds more correct than ensmallen.

Comment: **unlarge** opposite of **enlarge**

Comment: Although "ensmall" seems to be paired well with "enlarge", this word does not actually exist in English.

Answer (score 2):

What about switching the words around? Even though I agree "to enlarge or shrink the window" sounds funny, I think "to shrink or enlarge the window" sounds fine. It rolls off the tongue better - I'm guessing because of the way the vowels and consonants tie together.

'To enlarge or shrink the' has the combinations "oe, eo, rsh, and kth", whereas 'To shrink or enlarge the' has the combinations "osh, ko, re, and eth". It's hard to explain without drawing it but I hope you see what I'm getting at.

Many languages - such as Japanese, French, and Italian - tend to go vowel-consonant-vowel-consonant-vowel, etc., which allows you to talk faster and makes everything sound better when put together.

Answer (score 1):

Is "minimize" the word you are looking for?

Comment: That's what I'd use. As far as my browser window goes, if I hover over the "make window small" button, the word "minimize" actually pops up.

Comment: But minimize implies, minimizing to the task bar, at least from a UI perspective.

Comment: -1, minimize is antonym to maximize; this is quite different to enlarge/shrink.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options:

> Decrease
>   Contract
>   Narrow

Or

> Unexpand

Personally, I think "decrease" is the best.

Comment: I like "contract" in this context

Answer (score 0):

I would go with "increase or decrease the size of the window."

Answer (score -1):

Okay, this might be a good option: "minify."
According to Dictionary.com, it means "to minimize or lessen the size or importance of (something)."
Sounds like a winner to me!

Comment: Like "minimize" (in another answer), I would think this means to make it *as small as possible*.  But for this question, we may want it smaller, but not that small.

Comment: @GEdgar They are not the same. "Minimize" is the exact antonym for "maximize", while "minify" is the exact antonym for "magnify".

Answer (score -2):

The opposite is *smallen* – to make small-er.

Comment: Can you provide any more information to flesh out your answer? For example, what do dictionaries say? In your experience, do people use the word *smallen*?